# How is FBSession used

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm integrating facebook and I still don't see how the FBSession ties everything together.

This is how I think it works.

You need a new FBSession each app launch. (Is this true?). The FBSession also needs to be closed every time the app stops (if this is true, how do we start a new session without asking user to login again?)

As far as the session is concerned, [FBSession activeSession] is a global managed by the facebook sdk? Should we just use this as the default session anytime we want to pull data or check if a session is alive?

Assuming the above logic has worked out and you get the user id (fb id) then we feed that id to a FBImageView and we get a profile pic, but isn't this id changing every launch? So storing it on our server isn't helpful? Should we get the id every launch?

Please let me know what is right or wrong about the above statements, and an explanation of why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `activeSession` of `FBSession`. This way you don't have to create sessions yourself. Just use `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:...]` method of `FBSession` for activating `activeSession`, and on successful opening, You could use `FBSession.activeSession` for your Facebook requests. Good luck!
PS>
In order to restore `activeSession` you can do:

```
if (![FBSession.activeSession isOpen]) {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"] allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        }];
    }
```

which will open the session if it has cached token information without showing login UI.

Comment: Thank you! Why not just never close the session?

Comment: Anyways, session gets closed when your app is terminated. That's why, Facebook SDK provides this mechanism to restore the session.

Comment: And thats automatic?? Even if I dont put the close in the appdelegate?

Comment: I think so, but I didn't test that. You could give it a try, maybe it'll work for you ;)